# Android S4 running out of storage space

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, insufficient-memory

What safe files can I remove in order to gain storage space. My emails are not being viewed unless I delete Misc. Files.

Comment: Start at our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for helpful details :)

Comment: Do you have root access?

Answer (score 0):

You should start to gain space by unistalling you actually don't use; also most of space is used by games and APKs. APKs are "installation" files of Android application.
If the S4 has an external SD card slot, consider buyng an SD card to heavily mitigate the problem

Unfortunately Samsung is well know for adding tons of pre-installed applications that people mostly don't use at all! The only way to remove those apps is by first rooting the device, but Samsung (not only Samsung) will consider a rooted device as out of the warranty (if for any case you should need assistance a day)